# Java EE 5 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, data-access

Which version of Hibernate can I use with Java EE 5? Can I use the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.hibernate.org/, it says that newest 4.1.4 version can be used with Java EE 5.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, but I'm still slightly confused. From other questions asked on stackoverflow, I've come to realize that JPA 2.0 is not supported in a Java EE 5 environment, so if the latest version of Hibernate has a JPA 2.0 implementation will it still work in the environment that I'm working in?

Comment: I think yes. Which environment are you interested in particular?

Comment: Yes this should work, just include the Hibernate .jars and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Any. Neither JPA nor Hibernate restrict your choice of application server. They are independent.

Comment: What about the Java EE version? Is JPA 2 only supported by Java EE 6? If so, then I can't use it as Tomcat 6 only supports Java EE 5 correct?

Comment: I guess OP question is related about JPA 1 or 2, Hibernate 1, 2, 3 or 4, for compatibility with Java SDK 5 or 6.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I've updated the question again. Since I'm using Tomcat 6, I don't believe I need to know about EE 6. Thanks.

Comment: JPA is only vaguely related to JEE. It's just as much a stand alone technology and it doesn't have any dependency on a servlet container. You can use the classes on their own.

Comment: @RickMangi JPA is not only vaguely related, it's a mandated part of Java EE.